# Gratitude, Movement and Compassion

Tags: compassion, metta, right-effort

I noticed all the emotions mentioned in the title have a certain similarity. **Does Buddhism talk about movement or gratitude?**

Similarly, movement seems to occur spontaneously, but gratitude and compassion may be practised. **Is movement more of a reaction, and less constructive on that basis?**

Finally, movement seems akin to sympathetic joy. Would feeling sympathetic joy in itself -- i.e. the feeling or experience of it -- be constructive independently of practice, or is the *implementation* more constructive? **In other words, would practise like meditation or action bring benefit much beyond merely feeling moved?**

I guess I'm somewhat implying the question as well: **Do experiences without effort (e.g. merely *feeling* compassion) have any potential for spiritual growth?**

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that 'feeling moved' is just an emotional reaction. Meditation and practice are not about creating emotional reactions but about transcending them. The idea would be to establish who is moved, who is compassionate, who is emotional and so forth, as well as to engender compassion.

I suspect gratitude is just what happens naturally but maybe this should also be practiced. Perhaps this would be the same as practicing 'being moved' but such a practice would also require establishing who is being moved and even what 'moved' really means.

Experience without effort is not a practice but examining those experiences would be one. In short, I don't think there's anything in Buddhist practice one could call a free lunch.

All 'in my opinion' of course.

Answer (score 1):

No, "experiences without effort do not have any potential for spiritual growth..." since you never really experienced the freedom of letting go, the first stages in doing merits and then even share it. How can you ever trace merits of others and even rejoice with them? So all your perceptions are defiled and intellectual constructed and as always told, no way at all to gain samadhi if not having practiced Generosity, Sharing merits... You need to come in a [borderland](http://sangham.net/index.php/topic,8884.msg16105.html#msg16105) first (access concentration) and to do so, you need to leave home first. If you have no base for remembering your goodness, never did such, how to remind, how to make anussati? The same with Budddha, Dhamma, Sangha. Never met, what do you call in mind aside of your defilements?

You are hopeless lost with your "Dhamma-friends" and "teachers" who do not even know the path themselves (never trained even generosity and goodness by themselves, having much lack of gratitude as well, devoted to materialism) are there not capable to teach what to do to reach samadhi. It's a product of precious actions and not something you can be taught.

One may hope long on the possibility to gain freedom without work, effort and starting by the gross things.

And Nyom ask redundant, always the same question with other words. Skepic-nature (similar to moha charita) is said to be incapable or hardly to ever gain anything. Yet think if even lazy and greedy in addition...

*(Note: not given for trade, exchange, stacks and entertainment which keeps you bond here but as a door to exit if wished)*